# Does java compiler optimize unreachable exception catch branches?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throw, throws

Why is the code

```
void methodThrowsException() /*throws  Exception*/{
    try {
      // throw new Exception();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw e;
    }
}
```

well compiled?
AFAIK compiler doesn't analyse code for can it throw an exception or not.
Here obvious `throw e;` will never run (due to commented `//          throw new Exception();`), but why does compiler know this?

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javac compiler really doesn't do much of optimisation. But *simple* dead code detections and optimisations are yet possible.

In your example: the compiler can easily detect that the **try** block is empty. Empty try blocks can't throw, so all catch block code is essentially **dead**.

So the compiler *could* go in and simple drop the whole try/catch altogether here. Then there is nothing left that could throw an exception.

Which, when we use javap is exactly what we find in bytecode:

```
  void methodThrowsException();
    Code:
       0: return
```

And yes, the other answer is fully correct: this only works this way because you are using `Exception`, a more specific (checked) subclass will lead to a compiler error.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler will detect specific checked exception that are not thrown e.g.

```
void methodThrowsException() {
    try {
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

will result in compiler error:

```
exception java.net.URISyntaxException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
```

but it won't check runtime exceptions, or the exception hierarchy root types like `Exception`, `Error`, `Throwable`. This is explained in [JLS 11.2.3. Exception Checking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3).

Comment: Thank you very much for the information about compiler doesn't error on root types, it's very tricky...